# Функция sys.stdin [Python]

Tags: python

Здравствуйте
Никак не могу разобраться как работает sys.stdin

К примеру, в Shell'e ввожу:

```
       input_str = sys.stdin.read()
```

И ожидаю, что при клике Enter, я введу текст, ещё раз кликну Enter и после этого input_str будет ссылатся на введеный мной текст. Но в итоге, сколько бы раз я не кликал Enter, у меня всегда будет перенос на новую строку.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `read()` читает весь поток до самого конца, а Enter — это не конец, это всего лишь новая строка

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если read() заменить на readline(), то будет то, именно что я ожидал?

Comment: Ага, но `input()` всё равно лучше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно нажать Ctrl+D
http://chevalry.livejournal.com/190605.html

Чем input() не устроил?

Comment: Спасибо, то что и интересовало. Input устраивает, это просто хотел чисто для себя узнать.